# DNS timeout when using pcie wifi card

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, dns, timeout, windows-11

After some time of use hours or days dns request suddenly stop to work and timeout. Changing DNS server does nothing as it timeout on any of them ( tried ISP DNS, google, opendns all the same ). At the same time all other internet connection seems to work. E.g. I can ping I can use telegram just DNS not working.

Turning off firewall does nothing, have only windows firewall. It started to happen when I switched from lan cable to asus ax-58bt PCI wifi card. Plugging back LAN cable after this happened ( e.g. when dns stopped to work) dont do anything too and it still not working.
Only restart of pc work to fix it till it happens again. Not sure where to look at next any ideas ?

Tried with buildin driver and driver from asus site for pcie card, all same. And it wasnt happening purely on lan cable.

Windows 11

UPD in event viewer probable reason, but not yet figured cause

> A request to allocate an ephemeral port number from the global UDP
> port space has failed due to all such ports being in use.

UPD2 that event dont seem to be the cause. Happened today and i checked allocated ports with

> netstat -anob -p UDP

And there was not a lot of them, like less than 50 and certainly was opened.

Tried to stop dnscache service ( as admin) but

> net stop dnscache
> The requested pause, continue, or stop is not valid for this service.

In services list stop and restart also disabled. Tried to kill by process id from dnscache from netstat -> it was successfull e.g. it killed but than automatically started again, but dns still wasnt working.

Ipconfig when it happens:

```
ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : DESKTOP-1T4683A
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : stampinup.com

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) I211 Gigabit Network Connection
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 60-45-CB-9E-09-94
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Ethernet adapter Ethernet 5:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : TAP-Surfshark Windows Adapter V9
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-FF-AF-E0-76-99
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Unknown adapter Local Area Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : TAP-Windows Adapter V9
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-FF-9E-9E-91-55
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 10:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 6A-54-5A-CB-67-7C
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter WiFi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 68-54-5A-CB-67-7C
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.5(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : 3 сентября 2021 г. 18:55:19
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : 4 сентября 2021 г. 18:55:19
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 208.67.220.220
                                       8.8.4.4
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter vEthernet (Default Switch):

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-15-5D-0A-A2-00
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.26.144.1(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.240.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

In event viewer dont see anything other that could be cause and only happens before this situation.

UPD it seems to happen after pc inactivity for hour or so, when it resume it work. But as i remember first time it was without this, so might be just more often after resume but not solely

Comment: (1) When this happens, run `ipconfig` and add the output to your post, then try in the Services applet to restart the DNS Client service. (2) Check the Event Viewer for something related. (3) Which version of Windows? (4) Try a lower value for [MaxCacheTTL](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/dns/troubleshoot/disable-dns-client-side-caching)

Comment: @harrymc thanks, will add when this happens again. re 4 - dont think it will do anything as its about caching, while my issue that dns request timeout via nslookup or anything, so its not cached.

Comment: @harrymc thanks for remidning about 2. seems i found why it happens but not what cause it, will investigate further
> A request to allocate an ephemeral port number from the global UDP port space has failed due to all such ports being in use. 
https://superuser.com/questions/590686/tcpip-error-request-failed-due-to-all-such-ports-being-in-use

Comment: Is then this question a duplicate of the linked post?

Comment: @harrymc nope, i updated question with more info. when that happens port not really allocated

Comment: The output of `ipconfig /all` would be more helpful.

Comment: @harrymc replaced ipconfig with ipconfig /all as it happened again...

Comment: (1) I see "Lease Obtained" at 18:55:19. Is that the time that the problem happened? (2) And why your DNS server is Cisco OpenDNS, are you using a VPN?

Comment: @harrymc nope, it happened 1 minute before according to evetn from event viewer

>18:04:36 Name resolution for the name bolt.dropbox.com timed out after none of the configured DNS servers responded. Client PID 14128.

as for opendns -> well as i said i tried different dns servers, opendns, google, isp - all the same.

Comment: (I wouldn't stay with Cisco OpenDNS.) Try this: Go to *Settings > Network & Internet > Status > Change adapter options*, right-click the WiFi adapter and select Properties, click Configure button, Advanced tab, property Preferred Band. Check that it's set to "Prefer 5GHz Band". If not, set it, click OK and reboot.

Comment: @harrymc its not set, i changed and will test, but its hardly anything to do with my issue since after this happens even plugging in lan cable dont bring dns back so shouldnt be anything to do with wifi band

Comment: Let me know if the problem happens again. Apparently, Windows gets really confused when band change occurs.